# Trying to get my DTD and XML to work right

Tags: xml, dtd

I have been trying to get my XML to not only view the DTD but I receive an error while trying to validate my DTD, stating The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.  I am unsure what I am doing wrong or how to make it so that both files work.  Any help would be appreciated.

DTD:

```
    <!ELEMENT measurements (#PCDATA|distance|weight|volume)>
    <!ELEMENT weight (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT volume (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT distance (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST distance status (metric|imperial) #REQUIRED>
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE measurements PUBLIC "-//American Sentinel//XML Applications//EN" "measurements.dtd">
    <measurement>
      <weight>5</weight>
      <volume>10</volume>
      <distance>metric</distance>
    </measurement>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DTD, the declaration for `measurements` needs to be:

```
<!ELEMENT measurements (#PCDATA|distance|weight|volume)*>
```

This is because there is only one way to declare [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content).

Also, you've declared `measurements` (plural) in your DTD, but in your XML you're using `measurement` (singular). You'll have to either change the DTD or the XML. If you change the DTD, don't forget to change the doctype declaration in the XML.

One other thing is that the `status` attribute is declared as required in your DTD.

Example of fixed DTD and XML...

**DTD**

```
<!ELEMENT measurements (#PCDATA|distance|weight|volume)*>
<!ELEMENT weight (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT volume (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT distance (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST distance status (metric|imperial) #REQUIRED>
```

**XML**

```
<!DOCTYPE measurements PUBLIC "-//American Sentinel//XML Applications//EN" "measurements.dtd">
<measurements>
    <weight>5</weight>
    <volume>10</volume>
    <distance status="metric"/>
</measurements>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was definitely helpful and is definitely appreciated.